# BigQuery AVG time by hour

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column of type float64 as tt_time values in minutes 20.15 for each row.

I'm getting error of type cast when trying to calculate avg(tt_time) by hour.

No matching signature for aggregate function AVG for argument types: INT64, INT64. Supported signatures: AVG(INT64); AVG(FLOAT64); AVG(NUMERIC); AVG(BIGNUMERIC) at [3:10]

Comment: you need avg per hour per day or total avg per hour for the whole dataset?

Comment: per hour for the whole data set

Comment: actually better to show us sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to do this :

```
SELECT
    TIME_TRUNC(actual_time, HOUR) as hourly,
    Avg(POWER(TIME_DIFF(act_time, prom_time, HOUR), 2)) as avg_mse
FROM `bianalysis.bq_bi.orders`
group by TIME_TRUNC(actual_time, HOUR)
```

Comment: Thanks! I already calculated mse, I need to just use avg , without power, and using total_min column of type float64. At this point I think I need to cast it first. :(

Comment: yeah its not clear what you exactly want , please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: SELECT
    TIME_TRUNC(actual_time, HOUR) as hourly,
    CAST(Avg(TIME_DIFF(actual_time, promised_time, HOUR), 2) AS DATETIME) as avg_error
FROM `analysis.bq_bi.orders`
GROUP BY hourly....outputs error 
No matching signature for aggregate function AVG for argument types: INT64, INT64. Supported signatures: AVG(INT64); AVG(FLOAT64); AVG(NUMERIC); AVG(BIGNUMERIC) at [3:10]